# Javascript TypeError causing HTML5 video to... work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay I'm absolutely stunned / mind-blown or being superstupid.

```
  <div class="row videoholder">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <video id="movie" muted="false" autoplay="true" loop="" class="" poster="">
                <source src="{{url('/mp4/kleinste.mp4')}}" type="video/mp4">
                I'm sorry; your browser doesn't support HTML5 video in WebM with VP8 or MP4 with H.264.
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In javascript, I commented out some "old" code that needed recycling / is no longer needed. I've also put the call to the function in comments. (Don't mind this rubbish code)

```
//volume();

/*function volume(){
$('#volume').on("click", function()
{
    if($('#volume i').hasClass("fa-volume-up"))
    {
        $('#volume i').removeClass("fa-volume-up");
        $('#volume i').addClass("fa-volume-off");
        $('#movie').prop('muted', true);
    }else{
        $('#volume i').removeClass("fa-volume-off");
        $('#volume i').addClass("fa-volume-up");
        $('#movie').prop('muted', false);
    }
});
}*/
```

Now comes the crazy part. When I keep the volume() code commented, the HTML5 video doesn't play. Black screen.

When I uncomment the call to the function (not the function itself):

```
volume();
```

I obviously get an Uncaught TypeError stating the function volume does not exist, but the video **PLAYS**!

Does anyone have a clue what is going on here or should I leave a simple javascript error in my code in order to let this video work?

Complete JS: http://pastebin.com/AXqB26wi

Comment: miracle :) keep checking the code - you comment something else with the volume function

Comment: Src attribute of video ... you are using mustache? Or why is in curly brackets?

Comment: I would guess there is something after the `volume();` call that would cause the video to _fail_, but because `volume();` fails the rest of the code will not execute, so the video would run normally.

Comment: Once JS encounters an error, it ignores whatever follows.  It just does whatever it could up to that point.  So your error is likely somewhere else.  But it is beyond where the video starts playing.  In the other case, the entire code is working up to a further point that causes a more fatal error.  That's my guess...

Comment: I drop in a working mp4 and seems to be fine : https://plnkr.co/edit/MRmZ6nae8LxvO7n9x72F?p=preview

Comment: Added complete javascript. I don't get where 1) I'd cause to fail my video in JS and 2) Why it doesn't give an error...

Comment: @WaldemarIce I'm using Laravel :-)

Comment: @DenisMatafonov I'm not following... Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I could locate the problem within the mmenu() function. Seems like there are more people having issues with HTML5 video and mmenu (see https://github.com/FrDH/jQuery.mmenu/issues/162).

Putting all my content in one div seems to do the trick.

```
<body>
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```